# get FXML file nodes using java code

Tags: javafx, fxml

How to get elements or nodes from FXML file using `Java`, I know the way by using **initialization or by setting controller** class in FxmL . But I need to do it without any controller. I want to access the nodes inside the fxml file using.

**My FXML COde:**

```
HBox fx:id="hbx" id="hbx" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="100.0"
prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER"
```

**My java Code**

```
System.out.println(par.lookupAll("hbx"));
```

See my Code above, could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After loading the FXML file, you can use [Node#lookup()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Node node = fxmlParentPane.lookup("#nodeId");
```

Comment: Am getting null after doing this step

Comment: @GowthamIyer, it may means the node not found. Give an id (not fx:id) to the node. Or update your question with sample code.

Comment: Cee my Fxml and Java Code above

Comment: @GowthamIyer try as: HBox hbox = par.lookup("#hbx");