# how can I return text in code with color in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

There is my code:

```
public String changePassword(String _login, String _pass1, String _pass2) {
 if (_pass2 != _pass1) {
  return "Passwords not match!"; //Want to be red color
 } else {
  executeQuery("UPDATE persons SET username = username, password = password WHERE username = '" + _login + "' AND password = '" + _pass2 + "'");
  return "Well done!"; // Want to be green color
 }
}
```

In my fxml file this text will be displayed in Label.

Comment: Are you storing passwords in plain text? Bad programmer. No biscuit. Seriously though, this is an egregious violation of basic security principles. Read up on how to properly store passwords.

Comment: @tnw I was interpreting `_pass1` and `_pass2` as "password" and "confirm password" input fields (though I may be wrong...), in which case it's not a security issue. The SQL looks wrong though. Fortunately it will never get executed because the strings are not compared for equality in the correct way...

Comment: "I was interpreting _pass1 and _pass2 as "password" and "confirm password" input fields" - Yes, it is

Comment: tnw, Thanks for the help

Comment: @James_D I thought that too until I saw OP was matching the password in plain text on SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning a String you can return a boolean.

```
public boolean changePassword(...) {
    if(not correct) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

then where you call this method you can check what the result of this method is and act accordingly:

```
if(changePassword(...)) {
    //set label color to green and set text to well done
} else {
    //set label color to red...
}
```

Also if you are unaware, FXML nodes can be accessed either via a controller or a root construct. I prefer the root construct. You can do `@FXML private Label idOfLabelInFxml;` and then access it through there. More information can be found here: [get FXML file nodes using java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908074/get-fxml-file-nodes-using-java-code)